# How to solve ArgumentException : The parameter is not valid for drawing Arcs

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm making a custom winforms button in VB.Net with rounded edges and other features. I create a path using various inputs defined by the user and draw and fill it using pens and brushes.

When I call `e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brush1, Rect1)` and `e.Graphics.DrawEllips(Pen1, Rect1)` it just works fine without any problems, but when I try `e.Graphics.FillPath(Brush1, OuterPath)` and `e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pen1, OuterPath)` it doesn't work at all. I get this error:

> ArgumentException: The parameter is not valid

I tried giving the right types of each variable used in the process and not letting the compiler decide, creating more variables to calculate and manage the inputs individually to not make all the calculations in the inputs of each function, which makes my work easier honestly, and even using the `CType` function in the inputs of each function to make sure that the function understands what I want as inputs. But everything failed and I don't know what to do next to fix the issue.

Here is the code:

```vb
Private Sub MetaniumButton_Paint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    Dim PathWidth As Integer = Width - BorderSize / 2
    Dim PathHeight As Integer = Height - BorderSize / 2

    _Roundnes = RoundnesMemory

    If PathHeight < Roundenes.Height Then
        _Roundnes.Height = PathHeight - 1
    End If

    If PathWidth < Roundenes.Width Then
        _Roundnes.Width = PathWidth - 1
    End If

    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias

    Dim OuterPath As New GraphicsPath

    Dim Rec1 As Rectangle = New Rectangle(CType(BorderSize / 2, Int32), CType(BorderSize / 2, Int32), CType(_Roundnes.Width, Int32), CType(_Roundnes.Height, Int32))
    Dim Rec2 As Rectangle = New Rectangle(PathWidth - _Roundnes.Width, BorderSize / 2, _Roundnes.Width, _Roundnes.Height)
    Dim Rec3 As Rectangle = New Rectangle(PathWidth - _Roundnes.Width, PathHeight - _Roundnes.Height, _Roundnes.Width, _Roundnes.Height)
    Dim Rec4 As Rectangle = New Rectangle(BorderSize / 2, PathHeight - _Roundnes.Height, _Roundnes.Width, _Roundnes.Height)

    OuterPath.StartFigure()

    OuterPath.AddLine(CInt(_Roundnes.Width / 2 + BorderSize / 2), CInt(BorderSize / 2), CInt(PathWidth - _Roundnes.Width / 2), CInt(BorderSize / 2))
    OuterPath.AddArc(Rec1, 180.0, 90.0) ' Here is the problem and it could probably in any AddArc Function i used

    OuterPath.AddLine(PathWidth, CInt(_Roundnes.Height / 2 + BorderSize / 2), PathWidth, CInt(PathHeight - _Roundnes.Height / 2))
    OuterPath.AddArc(Rec2, -90, 90)

    OuterPath.AddLine(CInt(_Roundnes.Width / 2 + BorderSize / 2), PathHeight, CInt(PathWidth - _Roundnes.Width / 2), PathHeight)
    OuterPath.AddArc(Rec3, 0, 90)

    OuterPath.AddLine(CInt(BorderSize / 2), CInt(_Roundnes.Height / 2), CInt(BorderSize / 2), CInt(PathHeight - _Roundnes.Height / 2))
    OuterPath.AddArc(Rec4, 90, 90)

    OuterPath.CloseFigure()

    e.Graphics.FillPath(Brush1, OuterPath)
    e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pen1, OuterPath)

    Dim LabelCount As Integer = 0
    For Each l As Label In Controls
        LabelCount += 1
    Next
    Dim TextPlace As New Label With {.Name = "TextLabel",
                                     .Text = Text,
                                     .AutoEllipsis = True,
                                     .Size = New Size(Width -
 Margin.Left + Margin.Right + 2 * _Roundnes.Width) / 2, Height - (Margin.Top + Margin.Bottom + 2 * _Roundnes.Height) / 2),
                                     .TextAlign = _TextAlign,
                                     .ForeColor = _FontColor,
                                     .BackColor = _MetaniumBackColor,
                                     .Location = New Point((Width - .Width) / 2, (Height - .Height) / 2)}

    AddHandler TextPlace.TextChanged, AddressOf MetaniumButton_TextChanged
    AddHandler Me.TextChanged, AddressOf MetaniumButton_TextChanged
    Controls.Add(TextPlace)
    T += 1
    If LabelCount <= 0 Then
0:      For Each l As Label In Controls
            If l.Name = "TextLabel" Then
                l.Text = Text
                l.AutoEllipsis = True
                l.Size = New Size(Width - (Margin.Left + Margin.Right + 2 * _Roundnes.Width) / 2, Height - (Margin.Top + Margin.Bottom + 2 * _Roundnes.Height) / 2)
                l.TextAlign = _TextAlign
                l.ForeColor = _FontColor
                l.BackColor = _MetaniumBackColor
                l.Location = New Point((Width - l.Width) / 2, (Height - l.Height) / 2)
            End If
        Next
    ElseIf LabelCount = 1 Then
        For Each l As Label In Controls
            If l.Name <> "TextLabel" Then
                Controls.Remove(l)
            Else
                GoTo 1
            End If
1:          GoTo 0
        Next
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

When I track down the bug it seems the problem is in the `AddArc()` function, and I really don't know why it doesn't work. Any help appreciated.

BTW, I use VB.Net Express 2010 with .Net Framework 4.8.

PS: you can post an answer using either VB.Net or C# I can translate the code from both of them.

Comment: It might help if you included your `AddArc()` function. Also, VS 2010 is _really old_. The more recent versions are free and have some features that might directly address this issue.

Comment: If you get that exception, then you're creating shapes that cannot generate an arc or you have wrong measures, e.g., negative values. Difficult to say what that is, since some elements used here are not defined and their Type is not specified. Just print the rectangles to the Output pane to check their bounds -- You must remove any code that creates / removes Controls and any code that adds event handlers from the `Paint` handler, if that's actually code run in this handler -- Integer division is performed with a backslash, ``\``, no need of `CType()`, but you should use floating point values

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn That method is provided by the GraphicsPath class

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I wish I could use vs 2019 or 2022 but I can't, My PC can't handle the program, ok, after some bug-tracking, I find that there's an issue in a parameter of 
 ' Roundnes ' when I create a new button, this value starts with (0; 0) and I'm searching for a solution, am gonna link a video explaining the problem when it's done.

Comment: @Jimi  **what's your opinion ?**

Comment: here is the link
[link](https://youtu.be/ITFRNdzLxJc)

Comment: My opinion has already been expressed in my previous comment. This is something that just needs some debugging, to see what values go outside valid ranges. Missing pieces prevent others from debugging it for you -- You don't need to post videos, you have to post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Well, after some debugging, I found a way to initialize the value of ' Roundnes ' by checking it in the "Paint Sub" and everything is working properly. thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved My problem, and the answer was to initialize the value or `Roundnes` to (1,1) at least because my code creates the arcs of the edges using `Roundnes` to know how wide and long the curving edge
so the solution is to add this line of code before the code responsible for creating the arc.

```vb
If _Roundnes = New Size(0, 0) Then _Roundnes = New Size(1, 1)
```

And that's pretty much it! Thank you for helping me out!